# Is there a way to not display the rownames in structure of data

Tags: r, rshiny

I want to show only the the name of column and datatype of the column in str() function. I've tried doing this on server.r and it doesnt do the work.

ui.r

```
mainPanel(
              width = 12,
              uiOutput("data_browsing")
            )
```

server.r

```
 output$about_file <- renderPrint({str(data(), row.names = FALSE)})
```

[The example of data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKrxc.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need the name and the type, loop over the dataset with `sapply`, get the `class`

```
output$about_file <- renderPrint({
       tmp <- data()
       nm1 <- sapply(tmp, class)
       cat(paste('data.frame: ', nrow(tmp),
            ' obs. of ', ncol(tmp), ' variables:'), "\n")
      cat(paste(names(nm1), nm1, sep=";", collapse = "\n"), "\n")
   })
```

---

`str` doesn't have a `row.names` argument, but it won't give any error or warning message because there is a `...` argument

Comment: It works, but it is not that structured like how the str() function does. How can i make it like 

column name ; Datatype (then newline)
column name ; Datatype (then newline)
.....'

Comment: Im sorry for asking too much, but it returns collapse = "\n" as unexpected token for both collapse and the  = "\n"

Comment: @Melissa there was a typo.  I didn't include the `,` between the `sep` and `collapse`.  Can you try now

Comment: Ohh just notice something dear sir, i may need the number of column and rows to put before the str like str() function. I missed out this one just now. I am sorry

Comment: You meant something like `'data.frame': 150 obs. of  5 variables:`

Comment: Work like miracle! This literally mirror the str() function for the data